# How to get rid of negative feedback on answer even after editing?

Tags: discussion, support

I have the following answer here: *[HTML/CSS table with variable colums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183380/html-css-table-with-variable-colums/45183508#45183508)*

I updated this a while ago and since then I've gotten 3 votes I don't understand. I answered the guy's question perfectly. How can I remove these? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please be aware that Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. Please refrain from answering questions that appear to be too broad.

Comment: This is a terrible question. Hopefully it'll be deleted soon. You should be looking for better questions to answer, and probably wait a bit until you get the gist of what is a _good_ question for SO standards. This kind of _"gime me teh codez"_ questions are usually not well received by the community.

Comment: It is sad that the other answer managed to garner three upvotes, somehow.

Comment: Yup, one of the DV was mine, and you improved your post a lot so I reverted and upvoted your answer. Good job!

Comment: I had originally DV'd too, but then reverted once you edited it. Most people usually DV and move on and never look back at what they've voted on. I think the problem is that there is no way of knowing if the OP has changed and updated their questions/answers so people don't revert their DV's. Summed up by Bugs: 'Unfortunately there is nothing you can do'... except maybe don't answer low quality questions.

Comment: To sum up what has been said till now it sounds (mostly for new user) like: 'make an account and don´t answer anything - otherwhise you´ll get disappointed' Don´t know if this is the right way... maybe there is something to improve in the donwvote system?!

Comment: @Michael No, the downvote system is perfect, but some people should improve their questions though. Answer only high quality question and you won't be disappointed

Comment: @AlonEitan even if a question has like 5 answers or 6 answers, what are the chances that my answer will be of any use because there are 6 answer already?

Comment: @Michael - No. That's not what we are saying to new users. We are saying *please go through our help centre before posting anything on SO*. If asking poor questions is bad, answering them isn't exactly a good thing. Also, many new users have got a lot of upvotes on their first posts. It is always about the quality of the post(s). It has got nothing to do with how "new" the user is to SO

Comment: @J.Robinson If there are already 5-6 answers, and you see they are correct, then don't add yours too. Sometimes it's because of the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: @Alon Eitan and to decide if its a high or low quality question is nearly impossible for new users. And even if it´s a high quality question you might get downvoted cause you didn´t provided the 'ready to use' answer but guided the way to find it. In my oppinion the downvote button is used much too often by some users and there is no direct way (as already described) to see if the post has been edited and may be better now (furthermore there is no reason for anyone to do this).

Comment: @Michael I agree 100%. I think that not giving up is also important. But after a while you should be able to identify bad questions. There are patterns and of course questions that don't follow the guidelines of [ask]

Comment: @Michael, determining a question's quality is not nearly impossible. But it is true that sometimes it does take some time to be able to discern what fits and what doesn't in SO. Hence my advise _"wait a bit"_. Or to put it in different terms: first familiarize yourself with the place you are about to post, so you understand its rules, culture and conventions; then post. Or post nonetheless, but don't complain if you get negative feedback. :)

Comment: @AlonEitan this is what has honestly discouraged me from ever answering questions. However I'm really good at moderation of platforms. I'm currently a Moderator in Three Youtube Channels, and over 20 discord channels. So i have a knack for knowing what is allowed and what isn't once i get accustomed to the system i'm working within. So my question to you is, If i wanted to focus on moderation and asking good thoughtful questions, where do you suggest I start? I want to help this community as best as I can. It just seems answering questions is.... difficult... because of the FGitW Program. :/

Comment: I wish @Servy was here to answer, he always give the best suggestions

Comment: @TheLostMind this might not be what you want to say to new users, but this is what it (currently) sounds like. The main message is 'if you are downvoted, deal with it, cause it´s your fault that you spend your time to answer a question to a person you wanted to help' - I don´t know if this is the right approach for this kind of network. I know that the system works for nearly 90% but what I want to say that it can be improved and would help to prevent frustration for some users.

Comment: @J.Robinson I like your answer, voted you up. I also voted up the question, maybe it doesn't get deleted so easily then.

Comment: @Ctx, why would you upvote the question? Do you feel is useful and clear? That shows research effort?

Comment: @yivi this is what I already told: 'create an account and shut up' Might be the wrong way in this case. I agree that the downvote system as it is works perfectly , if you look from the right side ;)  starting here and step in with the wrong foot you´ll get downvoted and quit cause there is no way to impeove your answer and tell those who downvoted you that you´ve made it better.

Comment: @yivi This is solely to my disposition and I do not owe you an explanation for it (although I already gave a reason in my previous comment, which you obviously ignored)

Comment: @Ctx of course you can vote whichever way you like. Not contesting that. You said you voted the answer because you "liked it", which I understand. But you only mention that you upvoted the question and that since you've done that it might prove harder to delete. That doesn't say _why_ you want to protect this question. Do you feel it is a good question? A good fit for SO? I know you don't owe me or anybody an explanation. Just asking though, trying to undestand better my fellow SOers.

Comment: @yivi I think, the question is too broad but the answer is quite sophisticated and thus gives the _combination_ enough value to continue to exist. There are other examples, especially some self-answered questions come to my mind, where this is not unusual: Question is too broad, but a good answer compensates this.

Comment: this exactly shows what I wanted to explain. A smal part thinks the post (question/answer doesn´t matter) isn´t good or worth it, and with about 5 downvotes it get be ignored by hundred. Which wouldn´t be the problem, but there is NO WAY to improve and let the downvoters know. Wouldn´t it bring more benefit to the community if improving low quality posts would be honored to improve the quality of the whole network instead of downvoting it? I have made the experience, that even the dumbest question has a serious background for the one asking it. So improving might be better than deleting, or?

Comment: @Michael, you are using SO because it works. It works because of its voting system and its relatively harsh standards. Without that, it would be not much different from Quora or ExpertSexChange, and we all know how useful those are/were. We are better off without bad questions. They are not useful. They are not discoverable. They incite bad answers. They don't fulfill the purpose of having a quality knowledge repository.

Comment: @yivi I agree regarding the bad content stuff is not usefull, but you won´t get good information without the abillity to help people to improve their knowledge. It currently works, cause a small group provides good information and a huge group is downvoted or stays calm. So it will work till this small group retires. Without improvements this network will collapse, not now but it will. So my idea is to provide a ability to honor people who improve their knowledge and share it with all the others. Isn´t that what this community is about?

Comment: @Michael, no; as far as I'm aware, this community is about building a curated, hight quality programming knowledge repository structured in a QA format. Helping people while doing it is a (desirable) side-effect.

Comment: @yivi and where do you want to get this information from if noone asks questions any more and no one will answer them? SO, in my oppinion, is much more than a repo as which it may have started. Don´t get me wrong. The system is very good and provides usefull information but only while something is good it can´t be improved? I would only repeat my arguments at this point. I think I have made clear that I don´t want to burn down everything to build a new utopia[...]

Comment: [...]moreover this was an idea to make something wich is good even more better by providing the user an option to get honored for improving the knowledge and bringin it to a higher level.

Comment: Lack of people asking/answering questions, is not something SO is currently experiencing, IMO. People asking/answering bad questions, is. So I think your worries are misguided.

Comment: @yivi 'People asking/answering bad questions, is.' so if this is a problem on SO (which i agree) this is one more reason to honor improving this bad stuff to something valuable, isn´t it? You can just ignore it an leave it as it is cause it (currently) works, sure, but standing still was never a good idea in history ;)

Comment: @Michael, I don't understand what are you proposing.

Comment: I want to show that the vate system as it is today might be good, but might be worth to improve in future to avaoid frustration especially for the 'new ones'. It is sad to see that the only arguments I´ve heard so far are 'it works' and 'deal with it'. I think everything has already been written above, mybe the right person will read it at any time. Going on with this topic wouldn´t lead to anything,I think.

Comment: @Albzi, The user script [Get a list of posts you've voted on that have been edited](https://stackapps.com/q/6755) adds a tab in your profile which shows questions which have been edited after you voted on them.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll add it to my browser on my personal laptop. Unfortunately most of my time on here is spent while I'm at work and they are very particular about what I can and cannot add onto it (even addons in a browser!) so most of the time it won't help. Thank you though @Makyen

Comment: To be more specific on the advice to not answer low quality questions: Ideally what would happen after you improve your answer by editing is that you would get up votes from people viewing the question, *even if the down voters never come back and change their vote*. But that requires people to go to the question and down voted and/or closed questions are less likely to be seen by other users. Your answer, and any subsequent edits, are much less likely to be seen if your answer is on a poorly received question.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if someone saw the w3schools link at the top of your answer and downvoted immediately, then didn't bother reading the rest on principal.

Comment: literally asked a question of the correct approach to update RN ( which is a hard task) and got neg feedback ignorance is bliss.